# Straight lines plotting as curves

Tags: mercator, gmt

I'm trying to do something really simple, plot a rectangle using psxy on a .cdf grid file. Something like:

grdimage grid.cdf -JM20c -R-70/0/20/60 -Bf20g10 -K > image.ps
psxy rectangle.dat -JM -R -B -W0.5p -O >> image.ps

My rectanle.dat file is a two column file with 5 lon/lat points. Once plotted, the rectangle has two straight vertical sides and two curved upwards horizontal sides and I cannot figure out why. Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 4):

The manual page of psxy says:

*By default, geographic line segments are drawn as great circle arcs. To draw them as straight lines, use the -A flag.*